# Why does this JSX expression produce an odd result?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, reactjs

I was playing around with JSX when I found this oddity. Using the following JSX:

```
<div>{props.quote}</div>
```

Will produce the correct result:

[image]

But I wanted to add double quotes around the quote, so I tried:

```
<div>"{props.quote}"</div>
```

Which, to my surprise, gave the correct output:

[image]

I was expecting an output similar to this since it was a string literal:

[image]

Why doesn't it give me literally `"{props.quote}"` since `{props.quote}` is inside a string literal? Is this a bug with Babel?

---

<sup>Note: this is meant to be a self question-and-answer</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing is odd about the output at all. It is working as intended and there isn't a bug.

#### Semantics

The thing you have to understand is that JSX isn't JavaScript. Inside the `div`, that's not a string literal. It's just some text, similar to text nodes in HTML. The argument that it should be a string literal doesn't make sense because it *isn't* a string literal. The double quotes are treated like any other text inside an element, and `{props.quote}` is treated as an inline JSX expression where its value is displayed accordingly. You may have gotten it confused with:

```
<div>"{"{props.quote}"}"</div>
```

Here, the `{ … }` is an inline JSX espression, and is treated as a JavaScript expression inside an element. Thus, it *is* interpreted as a string literal and will literally give you `"{props.quote}"`.

#### Transpilation

Because *it's fundamentally not a string literal*, Babel doesn't transpile it like so. Using [the Babel REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code_lz=DwEwlgbgfARA3gBwE4HsEGcB0BHArigFwFMBfGYAenGiA), we can see what it's transpiled to:

```
"use strict";

React.createElement(
  "div",
  null,
  "\"",
  props.quote,
  "\""
);
```

As mentioned before, the double quotes are treated like any other text inside an element. Once transpiled, `<div>"{props.quote}"</div>` is just a `div` element with the following text as children:

- `"\""`
- `props.quote`
- `"\""`

The double quotes become literal text as children, and the value of `props.quote` is used. Babel treats the opening and closing `{ … }` as an inline JSX expression regardless of where it's at (unless inside another JSX expression inside a string literal). That expression evaluates to the string `The best way to predict the future is to create it` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

you can do that

```
<div>{`"${props.quote}"`}</div>
```